# How create application form can upload video?

Tags: forms, file-upload, webforms, upload, cloud

I want to create application form that can upload picture and video to some cloud(dropbox, googledrive, youtube). 
Google form with Google app script and google drive can upload only 10 mb. 
Anyone know how to do that pls?

Thank you very much

Comment: What's your preferable programming language?

Comment: Any web language or form like google form.

Comment: You need to understand that particular cloud api on which you would like to upload picture and videos.